# Store the state inside golang binary

Tags: go, binaryfiles, binarywriter

I am Developing an onpremise solution for a client without any control and internet connection on the machine.

The solution is to be monetized based on number of allowed requests(REST API calls) for a bought license. So currently we store the request count in an encrypted file on the file system itself. But this solution is not perfect as the file can be copied somewhere and then replaced when the requests quota is over. Also if the file is deleted then there's manual intervention needed from support.

I'm looking for a solution to store the state/data in binary and update it runtime (consider usage count that updates in binary itself)

Looking for a better approach.

Also binary should start from the previous stored State

Is there a way to do it?

P.S. I know writing to binary won't solve the issue but I think it'll increase the difficulty by increasing number of permutation and combinations for places where the state can be stored and since it's not a common knowledge that you can change the executable that would be the last place to look for the state if someone's trying to mess with the system (security by obscurity)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by requests in this context, do you mean physical requests to a server, because that would be the better place to hold this license. could you better define what what the idea of request means ?

Comment: This is an interesting question. (I think it was voted down because it's not quite clear what you're asking because what you mean by "binary" is not clear and also because if your encrypted file can be saved and restored then so can your binary file or any file for that matter.) I have some ideas if you are interested but as Volker implies there is no foolproof solution.

Comment: @ajr Like the question says I'm actually looking for better approach. Would love to hear your ideas. And I agree that there's no foolproof solution. Binary here is Golang executable

Comment: Volker answer is right (you cannot do it in software alone). On the other hand, you can use the good ol software protection dongle, which is hardware (still not 100% secure, but way better than software, if your business model allows to put a dongle in the offering). There are now USB dongles. As a starting point, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_protection_dongle

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to do it?

No.

(At least no official, portable way. Of course you can modify a binary and change e.g. the data or BSS segment, but this is **hard**, OS-dependent and does not solve your problem as it has the same problem like an external file: You can just keep the original executable and start over with that one. Some things simply cannot be solved technically.)

Answer (score 0):

If your rest API is within your control and is the part that you are monetizing surely this is the point at which you would be filtering the licensed perhaps some kind of certificate authentication or key to the API and then you can keep then count on the API side that you can control and then it wont matter if it is in a flat file or a DB etc, because you control it.

Comment: Its an onpremise deployment. On client's infra. No control .

Comment: I understood that this was an onpremise solution which is why I asked to clarify requests. Realistically if you want control then you need to retain control of the license side of things I think the best options would be to build in a service that can pull down a license from a server under your control. This way you can retract the license and have total control, to try to build this totally onpremise would leave you vulnerable to loosing control, as you are finding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to what you are trying to do (not to writing to the executable which) that will defeat casual copying of files.

A possible approach is to regularly write the request count and the current system time to file.  This file does not even have to be encrypted - you just need to generate a hash of the data (eg using SHA2) and sign it with a private key then append to the file.

Then when you (re)start the service read and verify the file using your public key and check that it has not been too long since the time that was written to the file.  Note that some initial file will have to be written on installation and your service will need to be running continually - only allowing for brief restarts.  You also would probably verify that the time is not in the future as this would indicate an attempt to circumvent the system.

Of course this approach has problems such as the client fiddling with the system time or even debugging your code to find the private key and probably others. Hopefully these are hard enough to act as a deterrent. Also if the service or system is shut down for an extended period of time then some sort of manual intervention would be required.